# Function * not working with Node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
//userDao.js
module.exports = {
   * getSync(request) {
    let database = SYSTEM.getDatabase('databaseName');
    let skip = (request.pageSize || 10) * (request.pageNumber || 0);
    let result = yield database.models.modelName.find(request.query || {})
        .limit(request.pageSize || 10)
        .skip(skip)
        .sort(request.sort || {})
        .select(request.select || {})
        .exec((data) => {
            console.log('----------------- ', data);
            return data;
        });
    console.log('=================== ', result);
    return result;
   }
};

//userService.js
const UserDao = require('./userDao.js');
module.exports = {
   get: function(){
        return UserDao.getSync(request);
   }
}
```

I want to get data from Mongo DB synchronously, so want to use * and yield. other wise normal using callback its working fine.

While running this application it says getAsync is not a function at line 'UserDao.getAsync(request);'
I am using reference from "http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_oop-besides-classes.html"

Please help me resolve,

Comment: Try wrapping `database.models.modelName.find` into a Promise. Then your resolve() should be in the exec function

Comment: What makes you think `yield` is synchronous? It depends on how the generator is used, and in this case it likely is asynchronous.

Comment: "*it says getAsync is not a function at line 'UserDao.getAsync(request);*" - the code you posted neither has that line, nor defines an `getAsync` method anywhere. Did you mean `getSync`?

Comment: The first thing is that it is a function in the code above, so it's not clear what the problem is.  The second one is that generators don't do anything asynchronous, unless you make them to. Use async..await (available in Node 8).